# How are multiple keystroke shortcuts called?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminology

Do combinations of sequential keystrokes, like
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>
have any specific name?

The [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_shortcut) does not call them anything:

> Some keyboard shortcuts, including all shortcuts involving the Esc
>   key, require keys (or sets of keys) to be pressed individually, in
>   sequence. These shortcuts are sometimes written with the individual
>   keys (or sets) separated by commas or semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

A series of keystrokes can be called a macro:

> A macro (short for "macroinstruction", from Greek μακρός 'long') in computer science is a rule or pattern that specifies how a certain input sequence (often a sequence of characters) should be mapped to a replacement output sequence (also often a sequence of characters) according to a defined procedure.

[source from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_(computer_science))

Answer (score 0):

I have heard them called keyboard shortcuts and keyboard combinations. Some applications use a single key to perform an action, such as <kbd>F1</kbd> for help. In my opinion that is a shortcut. Using multiple keys at once, like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>, would be a combination. They seem to be interchangeable though.